# How can I convert a low resolution image to a mesh?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have a low resolution Image I want to recreate as a 3D object. I was thinking of making 7 separate "layers" to depict foreground and background elements. Basically, once the layers were complete they would stack to create a 3D picture. Each layer would have its own textured color. I would combine them at different depths.

I am bit unsure how to proceed with the process of this. Would it be best to create each layer, extrude to the right depth and then snap them together and join them into a single object? The idea is to 3D print this as a personal project. Reference is attached.

Comment: Please see this link
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/is-it-possible-to-give-a-texture-thickness/16525#16525

Comment: Are you looking for an automated conversion? Or how to re-create a similar effect in 3D. Please make this clear in the question - since they're almost entirely separate tasks.

Comment: Suggest using a vector application to do a bitmap to vector conversion. Then you can load the SVG into Blender as colored 2D curves which you can add depth to.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33071/create-a-mesh-from-image-with-transparency/33113#33113

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should model the whole scene (make some quick low-poly models) and then use the ***Remesh Modifier***. Set its mode to *Blocks*. Apply the modifier and then paint the model.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Will that work properly with a low-poly 2-D model?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it on some primitive objects and it works fine.