# Exporting a PNG file and creating a flat object which looks like the texture

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, export

I am a complete beginner at blender so this question may sound very trivial to someone, please don't judge.

I imported a png file to into blender and basically what I want is to create a 2D object which has texture and form of the logo of the png file. Right now I have a black square object where the logo is laoded onto, but I want to remove everything black from the 2D Plane except the logo itself if you get what I mean. Does anyone know how I can do that ? 
Or in other words, I want to create a flat Object which has the form of the logo of my texture, so I can export it into a Obj file and render it in my program.

I don't want to go into thousands of tutorials because I won't use blender for anything else after that.

Comment: "*so I can export it into a Obj file and render it in my program*" If you are going to export to OBJ then [all texture work will most likely be lost](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541), exporting just a plane seems pointless. If you don't want to invest the time to learn Blender and just want someone to do it for you there's a job section over at [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org)

Comment: I suggest adding some images to your question to explain what you mean.

Comment: If you have a logo I suggest tracing it as paths/vectors in a vector drawing program (like inkscape, illustrator, or similar) and save the traced paths as SVG. Then you can import that into blender and work on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/tracing-a-monochrome-image-into-a-3d-extruded-object-with-a-script/1610#1610

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object/52564#52564

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88196/map-pixels-to-a-grid-of-faces/88209#88209