# Create a mesh from image with transparency (Redux)

Tags: python, mesh, image, geometry, conversion

I'm following @zeffii answer from [Create a mesh from image with transparency](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33071/create-a-mesh-from-image-with-transparency) but have the following error.

"KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Ao8jf.png" not found'"

The answer was posted in 2015. I'm using 2.79 so I wonder if the script is out-dated?

I am not sure what to try next. Googling this error has not helped.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is your image renamed to Ao8jf.png? It looks like the script is looking for an image named to aYlTzbV.png, if you haven't changed it already. I haven't used scripting much, but this may be a name error.

Comment: Thanks Akados. Yes I changed the filename to match the image in the previous answer.