# Voxel data as image sequence in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have image sequence of an object. How to render it in cycles as voxel or volume?

Image sequence represents a slices of 3d object. Images are in .png. I would like to turn theese slices in 3d object in cycles probably using volume shader but I don't know how.
I have 900 images as slices.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add some more details as to what you are looking for?  I'ts kind of hard to tell what you are after.

Comment: I've updated it. Should I upload sequence to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate/overlap with http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/is-it-possible-to-give-a-texture-thickness

Comment: Voxel data should be read as volume material.

Comment: I have found how to do it in BR. https://mollermara.com/blog/blender-brain/ Could you tell me  ho wo to it in cycles?