# Cooky cutter from svg file for 3D printing

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-printing

I have the idea to create a cooky cutter from a svg file. What I basically do is importing the svg and extruding it into z direction. But now I have to make the material anyhow solid, ideally some kind of V shape to have a sharp edge and a more solid part.

[image: extruded svg curve]

At the moment I don't know how I have to modify only one side of my curve to expand it. I found a link to a thingiverse file which actually shows what I am trying to do: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:35719 
Here you have a solid part at the bottom, perfect for printing and a sharp edge for cutting.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Maybe this is another example which would help but I am not able to add this to my curve/mesh: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:33096
Here they just added a border to the shape.

Comment: Could you give me more details? I can convert my curve into a mesh and give it also some height. My problem is to extrude one side of this curve to get something like a knife. The thingiverse example shows this very nicely.

Comment: Please show an image in your question of your curve.  Please see this ..... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47906/find-the-color-at-a-particular-surface-point-on-a-mesh/47916#47916 .... where an image creates a mesh.

Comment: I added an image how far I am at the moment. Would love to make the curve solid, so 1mm even thickness and adding a border to it like in my second link

Comment: If you wish to make curved surface to be [thicker in the base and less thin in the top](http://i.imgur.com/uJJaUgH.jpg) then don't convert curve to mesh because when it's still curve it can use Bevel object, which can be any other curve.

Answer (score 2):

**Solidify Modifier**

[image]
Image above. The blue flower shape has the solidify modifier.  You can press apply to make it permanent.  You may need to look closely to see the thickness on top, and clicking on the image will show a larger image.

You can scale a ring smaller.  You can also scale the extrusion as a modelling technique.

[image]

Loop Cut and Slide
In the image below extra rings of vertices were added along the edge.