# Tracing Geometry with an Alpha Channel?

Tags: mesh, transparency

I have not used a forum before to get an answer for a technical question, so bear with me.
also, my spelling is pretty bad :)
ok so,
I have an alpha channel for a logo that I want to animate. I want the logo to have depth. as in not just the flat image plane but extruded.

is there a way to cut out the logo from the image plane using the alpha image to manipulate the geometry?
ideally, there would be a way to have a blender automatically place edges around the edge of the logo so that I can just delete the parts that aren't needed.

any solutions???

Comment: Hello :). This answer could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160161/

Answer (score 1):

For a logo trace it in a vector drawing program and export it as SVG.
No need to deal with alpha or pixels.

read the following links:

[How do I turn my PNG Image into a mesh object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object/52564#52564)

[Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape/23171#23171)