# Automatically cut mesh using alpha maps

Tags: mesh, transparency

I was wondering if it is possible to automatically cut an object depending on the transparent parts in it (alpha map)
Is it possible to be cut automatically without using a Boolean mod or knifing?
I was searching on YouTube and Google but couldn't find anything, even searched on this website, I can provide screenshots of what I want to do if needed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173450/tracing-geometry-with-an-alpha-channel/173458#173458

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @susu that is not my question

Comment: Then clarify what you want. Edit your question please.

Comment: @susu done, do you need screenshots?

Comment: maybe create a svg from alpha and import to Boolean it.