# Can you use a PNG Alpha Channel to extrude?

Tags: transparency

I'm recreating some historical stone markers with the inscriptions etched in. My question is if I am able to get a png of the front etchings, would it be possible to extrude just the etching marks from the Alpha Channel and be able to boolean it into the face I want them in? I'm not very experienced in Alpha Channels in the first place, so I'm not even sure if theres a way to use them to be able to do this.

Comment: you can use the alpha channel as bump map or as displacement.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173450/tracing-geometry-with-an-alpha-channel/173458#173458