# How to fill the edges of solidify modifier with alpha material?

Tags: materials, modifiers, transparency

[image]

So basically I have a simple plane uv unwrapped to this shape on the left. Using color ramp to indicate that all the white area should be used an the alpha channel so the model itself looks transparent. Then I used a solidify modifying to extrude the plane, giving this thickness to the geometry. However, it just seems that blender doesnt fill the edge of the alpha material with any possible way that i can understand. I tried using a second material for the "material index offset" option but it just ends up filling the entire edge of the box. The only solution that I can think of this is to actually model this shape on a plane with vertices and extrude, apply a second material to the edges. But that's really not a good option because it creates many more polygons, and this is a huge landscape project. Can someone please point me to the right direction on this problem should be resolved? Thank you!

Comment: Related - but most likely far too complicated for your needs : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84618/29586
Note that the solidify works on the geometry, not the image - which is why you're seeing the unexpected behaviour. The only options are to either fake it (which is not simple) or to create the additional geometry (as you described) and then 'solidify'.

Comment: Note that alpha materials also reduce the performance, even more so than a few more vertices and faces. You could vectorize your image in inskcape fo example, and import the resulting svg in blender, then solidify the resulting object. My 2 cents

Comment: ok thank you both, i saw that post, a bit too complicated for my understanding. I thought this would be a simple default function in blender. Ok maybe i should try drawing the geometry instead.

Comment: Here's a much simpler solution using the Displace modifier: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160161/111042, but i think you'll have to subdivide your plane into many faces, which you seem to want to avoid