# Is there an easy way to model this romantic / floral pattern?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I've just started learning Blender and I'm trying to model a key with a help of this reference picture but I feel like extruding and manually placing all vertices to cover it is very time-consuming.

[image]

[image]

Is there an easier way of modeling strange patterns like this one?

Comment: Hello :). In cases like these, it might be beneficial to use as little manually placed vertices as possible, and smooth them out using subdivision. Or convert the image into curves (in Illustrator) and import into Blender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping a Pattern over an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160146/wrapping-a-pattern-over-an-object)

Comment: @JachymMichal Sorry for not responding earlier, I've had some success getting the rough shape using curves, as you mentioned earlier. The post you linked to seems to be exactly what I'm looking for though. Added to bookmarks :)

Comment: Glad it helped :). Good luck with your project and feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck anywhere.